# GASでgoogle driveフォルダに「投稿者」の権限付与

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-sdk

共有ドライブ上では「投稿者」の権限種類があるものの、その権限をGasで付与するメソッドが見当たらなくご質問となります。
マイドライブ上ではDriveAppのaddViewersなどございますが、共有ドライブだけの特殊な権限付与はGasでは実装できないのでしょうか？

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

手元の環境向けにシンプルなGASを書いて実行してみる限りでは、共有ドライブに対する`DreiveApp.Folder`オブジェクトに対する操作としては以下のようになるみたいです。

- `addEditor()`

  - [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder?hl=ja#addeditoremailaddress)上の記述: 編集者
  - Googleドライブ上での付与権限: **投稿者**
- `addViewer()`

  - [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder?hl=ja#addvieweremailaddress)上の記述: 閲覧者
  - Googleドライブ上での付与権限: 閲覧者

よって、表題の通り「投稿者」権限を付与する場合だと、対象フォルダのオブジェクトの`addEditor`メソッドを使えば良さそうでした。

#### ※検証時のコードスニペット

```js
function myFunction() {
  // YOUR_FOLDER_ID は共有ドライブのトップでも、内部のフォルダでも同様に動作しました
  const target = DriveApp.getFolderById(YOUR_FOLDER_ID);
  target.addEditor(YOUR_TARGET_EMAIL);
}
```

### 補足

下記の権限に関しては、`DriveApp`のAPIと連動している様子がなさそうで、同種のメソッドは見当たりませんでした。
ただし、「高度なサービス」として[Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive?hl=ja)が存在するため、GAS経由でこちらを利用することで操作できるかもしれません。

- `閲覧者（コメント可）`
- `コンテンツ管理者`
- `管理者`

Comment: @attakei様
早速にご回答いただきありがとうございます。本件、いただいたもので解決できました。マイドライブと共有ドライブ上では扱われ方が変わるのですね